# What did Jesus mean in John 1:47 regarding Nathanael: "an Israelite indeed"?

Tags: john

There is a curious exchange between Jesus and Nathanael:

> **John 1:47**: "Jesus saw Nathanael coming to Him, and said of him, 'Behold, *an Israelite indeed*, in whom there is no deceit!'” (emphasis added).

While it is very interesting that Christ declares that Nathanael "had no deceit" (a question for another day), what does Jesus mean by "an Israelite indeed"? Wasn't Jesus essentially surrounded by Israelites?

Comment: Pet peeve - why do people insist on spelling Nathanael 'Nathaniel'?! :)

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Thanks for that! I actually try hard to getting spelling correct. I've corrected it.

Comment: He simply means that as a rhetoric by complementing him, implying that Israelites are full of deceit. In other words, he could rarely find any righteous men. *Behold truly an Israelite, in whom is no deceit!* (SLT)

Answer (score 5):

Not all are of Israel who think they are of Israel. Nathanael was a real Israelite BECAUSE there was no guile

Comment: Interesting answer. + 1.

Comment: Israel =  one who is in covenant with God. But to be in covenant with God is to be circumcised of the heart NOT to simply be ethnic Israel..so yeah, having no guile would be a sign that he was a true Israelite indeed

Comment: Thank you for your Answer: it gave me inspiration for my Answer :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Of course "no deceit" was a play on Jacob/Israel, who obtained Isaac's blessing out of deceit.  People wonder why Jesus used "true Israelite" rather than "true Jew."  Of course the ladder reference alluded to Jacob.  But, "true Israelite" seems to say that Nathaniel had a sincere focus on keeping the covenant with Jacob, including God's covenant with the children of Israel at Sinai.

Jesus did say:

> He answered, “I was sent only to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.”
> (Matt 15:24, ESV)

Other than this, commentaries move toward speculation.

1. Eli Lizorkin-Eyzenberg interprets this a being more inclusive:

> It is highly significant for the kind of questions we are asking in this book that Jesus referred to Nathanael, not as Ioudaiois (Jew/ Judean) in whom there is no guile, but in a more generic way: “an Israelite (Ἰσραηλίτης) indeed in whom there is no guile.” (vs. 47) This terminology was perfectly fitting for a Samaritan audience as well as for other Israelite movements. (It would probably have been understood by so-called God-fearers as well.) Nathanael’s response, therefore, points in the direction of a non-Judean audience. Nathanael referred to Jesus not as the King of the Ioudaioi only, but as the King of Israel (vs. 49).
> --
> Lizorkin-Eyzenberg, Eli. *The Jewish Gospel of John: Discovering Jesus, King of All Israel (p. 20). Jewish Studies for Christians.* Kindle Edition.

2. J. P. Lange's interpretation:

> The word of the Lord addressed not directly to Nathanael, but to others on his approach. An Israelite indeed: that is, not merely a Jew, but a Jew of the higher theocratic turn. [Israelite is the theocratic and the most honorable title of the descendants of Abraham, in commemoration of Jacob’s glorious victory of prayer (Gen. 32:28; Acts 2:22; 3:12; 5:34; 13:16; Rom. 9:4, etc.). The Ishmaelite and the Edomite were Abraham’s seed as well as the Jews, but not Israelites. That was the exclusive title of the people of the covenant. With many this title was indeed a mere name, or even a contradiction and reproach, as the title Christian (i.e., follower of Christ) is with a multitude of Christians so-called. But Nathanael was not merely a carnal descendant of Jacob, an Israelite after the flesh, but an Israelite in spirit, a genuine son of that new Jacob or Israel who had in faith and prayer wrestled with God and prevailed. Probably he was engaged in meditation and prayer under the fig-tree, and thus truly a wrestler with God, like Israel of old. A reference to that event in the history of Jacob which gave rise to his new name (Gen. 32:28; Hos. 12:4), is as likely, as the reference to Jacob’s ladder in ver. 51 (see below) is certain. Perhaps the scene took place on the very spot which tradition assigned for the wrestling of Jacob.
> --
> Lange, J. P., & Schaff, P. (2008). *A commentary on the Holy Scriptures: John* (p. 95). Bellingham, WA: Logos Bible Software.

3. A. T. Robertson's interpretation:

> **An Israelite indeed** (ἀληθως Ἰσραηλειτης [alēthōs Israēleitēs]). “Truly an Israelite,” one living up to the covenant name, Israel at its best (Rom. 2:29), ...
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). *Word Pictures in the New Testament* (John 1:47). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

4. R. E. Brown simply sees it as making the connection to Jacob's ladder:

> *a genuine Israelite*: A contemporary popular etymology of the name Israel was “one who sees God”; in v. 51 Nathanael is promised a vision of heavenly things. In the same verse, reference is made to the heavenly vision of Jacob (Israel) in Gn 28:10-17. The original Israel is being contrasted here with Nathanael. Jacob’s guileful character was well known, but in Nathanael “there is no guile.”
> --
> Brown, R. E., Fitzmyer, J. A., & Murphy, R. E. (1996). *The Jerome Biblical commentary* (Vol. 2, p. 426). Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-Hall.

Comment: _Of course the ladder reference alluded to Jacob_ Nathanael is called by Jesus "a true Israelite in whom there is no deceit" at v. 47. The _possible_ allusion to "Jacob's ladder" only comes at v. 51. Are you suggesting that referring to Nathanael as  "Israelite" was part of a play on words whose goal was the alleged allusion to "Jacob's ladder" 3 verses later? Bah ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the relevant context:

> <sup>45</sup> Philip found Nathanael and told him, “We have found the
> one Moses wrote about in the law, and the prophets also wrote about –
> Jesus of Nazareth, the son of Joseph.” <sup>46</sup> Nathanael
> replied, “Can anything good come out of Nazareth?” Philip replied,
> “Come and see.” <sup>47</sup> Jesus saw Nathanael coming toward him
> and exclaimed, “Look, a true Israelite in whom there is no deceit!”
> <sup>48</sup> Nathanael asked him, “How do you know me?” Jesus
> replied, “Before Philip called you, when you were under the fig tree,
> I saw you.” <sup>49</sup> Nathanael answered him, “Rabbi, you are the
> Son of God; you are the king of Israel!” <sup>50</sup> Jesus said to
> him, “Because I told you that I saw you under the fig
> tree,<sup>**10**</sup> do you believe? You will see greater things
> than these.” <sup>51</sup> He continued, “I tell all of you the solemn
> truth – you will see heaven opened and the angels of God ascending and
> descending on the Son of Man.”<sup>**17**</sup> ([John 1:45-51](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=John%201:45-51&passage=john%201:45-51)
> NET)

The NET Bible has a couple of interesting footnotes.

<sup>10</sup>**sn** Many have speculated about what Nathanael was doing under the fig tree. Meditating on the Messiah who was to come? A good possibility, since the fig tree was used as shade for teaching or studying by the later rabbis (Ecclesiastes Rabbah 5:11). Also, the fig tree was symbolic for messianic peace and plenty (Mic 4:4, Zech 3:10.)

<sup>17</sup>**sn** The title *Son of Man* appears 13 times in John’s Gospel. It is associated especially with the themes of crucifixion (3:14; 8:28), revelation (6:27; 6:53), and eschatological authority (5:27; 9:35). The title as used in John’s Gospel has for its background the son of man figure who appears in Dan 7:13-14 and is granted universal regal authority. Thus for the author, the emphasis in this title is not on Jesus’ humanity, but on his heavenly origin and divine authority.

So, there is a "good possibility" that Nathanael was "[m]editating on the Messiah who was to come".

Now compare this with what Jesus said later to the Jewish Leaders:

> <sup>39</sup> You study the scriptures thoroughly because you think in
> them you possess eternal life, and it is these same scriptures that
> testify about me, <sup>40</sup> but you are not willing to come to me
> so that you may have life. ([John 5:39-40](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=John%205:39-40&passage=john%205:39-40))

Nathanael is a Jew who sincerely expects the Messiah; the Jewish Leaders are too self-righteous to even consider that they need the Messiah, a Saviour.

Answer (score 1):

Christ said to Nathanael that He had seen him ***under the fig tree***, which some have interpreted as ***searching the Scriptures under the fig tree*** or ***praying (having an experience of God under the fig tree)***. [Juchre.org](https://juchre.org/articles/fig.htm) explains:

> ***The fig tree was a common place for prayer***, especially for young rabbinic students, which Nathanael may well have been. If he was specifically under a fig tree when Philip called him, chances are he was in prayer.

Also

> The fig tree is in the rabbinic literature sometimes considered a place for prayer and meditation (see Lightfoot, Commentary on the New Testament from the Talmud and Hebraica, vol. 3, pp. 246-47) ([source](https://www.studylight.org/language-studies/aramaic-thoughts.html?article=257))

If you look at the meaning of the name ***Israel*** is, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_(name)) mentions that:

> According to the biblical Book of Genesis the patriarch Jacob was given the name ***Israel*** (Hebrew: יִשְׂרָאֵל‎, Standard Yisraʾel Tiberian Yiśrāʾēl) after he wrestled with the angel (Genesis 32:28 and 35:10).

Some have argued that ***Israel*** means ***he who struggles with God***.

BUT

> In Jewish and Christian texts from the Greco-Egyptian area during Second Temple Judaism and beyond the name was understood to mean "***a man seeing God***" from the ʾyš (man) rʾh (to see) ʾel (God).

So it is not excluded that by calling him an Israelite, Christ actually tells him that yes, Nathanael ***has seen God (under that fig tree)***. Actually, the fact that He adds ***in whom there is no guile*** points to Christ's knowledge of what was ***IN*** Nathanael's soul.

Either way, Christ reveals His omniscience to Nathanael, without saying ***I am omniscient***. He simply tells him that He saw him (*and what was happening in his heart at that moment*, if you accept this interpretation) in a place where Christ was not present *in the Body*.

Comment: I totally disagree with the ***I am omniscient*** attributed to Jesus, but +1 for the good argument.

Comment: @MigueldeServet St Cyril of Alexandria says: " The Saviour undid his surmise, saying that even before his meeting and conversing with Philip, He had seen him under the fig-tree, though not present in Body. Very profitably are both the fig-tree and the place named, pledging to him the truth of his having been seen. For he that has already accurate knowledge of what was with him, will readily be admitted." But yes, maybe I put it too strongly.

Comment: And I should put "I disagree", dropping the "totally" :)

Comment: No worries, I do understand. I simply think Christ is trying to reveal Himself to Nathanael (as Divine), and it seems to have worked, because Nathanael exclaims afterwards: "Rabbi, thou art the Son of God; thou art the King of Israel." Imagine, he doesn't call him the Messiah, but straight **the Son of God**...

Comment: Nathaniel says, “Rabbi, you are the Son of God; you are the king of Israel!”, so that "Son of God" is not said in the sense of [Matt 1:20](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Matt%201:20&book=matt&chapter=1&verse=20) or [Luke 1:35](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Luke%201:35&book=luke&chapter=1&verse=35), and certainly not in a metaphysical sense, but in a Messianic sense.

Comment: I guess you need to have this discussion with [St Cyrill](https://www.tertullian.org/fathers/cyril_on_john_02_book2.htm), who says: "Nathanael knows that God Alone is Searcher of hearts, and giveth to none other of men to understand the mind, considering as is likely that verse, God trieth the hearts and reins. For as accruing to none else, the Psalmist attributed this too as peculiar to the Divine Nature only. When then he knew that the Lord saw his thoughts in his mind, straightway he calls Him Master, and confesses Him Son of God, and he affirms Him to be wholly and by Nature God."

Comment: Yes, unfortunaately Cyril of Alexandria (c. 376 – 444), like many Church Fathers, was imbued with Greek metaphysics ... and he read the Scripture through that "lens" ...

Comment: Ok, I think here is a good point where we can say "Let's agree to disagree."

Answer (score 1):

Jesus lamented the hypocrisy of Jews and Jewish leaders. His assessment of Jews (in general) was:

> "This people doth draw nigh to Me with their mouth, and with the lips
> it doth honour Me, but their heart is far off from Me" (Mt. 15:8. Also
> [Isa. 29:13; Ezk. 33:31](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=Isa.29.13%20Ezek.33.31&options=HNVUG)).

Jews, His own people, rejected Jesus, the Messiah who came according to Law and Prophets. Nathanael was not like them. He, according to Jesus' word,  **the pure in heart** (Mt.5:8).

Now, instead, I would like to share the following commentary of Lenski on John 1:47:

"This word of Jesus concerning Nathanael can be understood only in connection with the conversation of Philip with Nathanael. In his divine way, Jesus knew what the two had said and how Nathanael, instead of stiffening himself in his doubt about Nazareth, yielded to his desire for the Messiah and came along with Philip. It cost Nathanael some effort to come to a man from Nazareth; Jesus knows what it cost him, and this rejoices his heart. Thus, we can not reduce this word of Jesus to mean merely that Jesus sees the character of the man Nathanael; we must elevate it to mean the character and quality of his being an Israelite, a man who is absolutely sincere about Israel's hope and salvation, so sincere that he does not allow the mention of Nazareth to turn him away from Jesus. Jesus' word does not mean that in some way Nathanael will prove himself an Israelite, indeed, as Simon would eventually be a Rock, but that right here and now Nathanael is truly what he is.
The relative clause, "in whom is no guile," elucidates the adverb ἀληθῶς, and δόλος is cunning or deception, as when one uses bait to catch fish or some cunning means to secure personal advantage. Nathanael was without duplicity, altogether sincere. David calls such a man blessed, Ps. 32:1, 2. Most men lack this complete sincerity. Professing love to Christ, they still secrectly love the world and the flesh; promising faithfulness, the promise does not fully bind their hearts. This δόλος kept the Jewish nation from Christ, proved the curse of Judas, almost wrecked Peter. Church men and entire church bodies, while making loud profession sonoro tono, yet squint secretly at popular opinion, human authorities, supposed advantages, and with fair sounding excuses deviate from the Word. "Blessed are the pure in heart, for they shall see God," - (Lenski New Testament Commentary - Lenski New Testament Commentary – The Interpretation of St. John's Gospel.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be read as a reference to the story of Jacob, who

- was full of deceit
- had the vision of angels ascending and descending along the ladder
- God changed his name to Israel, which can be interpreted as "he/she who sees God"

But Nathanael

- was called "an Israelite indeed, in whom is no guile!"
- was told he would see a similar vision (angels ascending and descending on the son of man) (v1.51)
- was seen *by* Jesus

Answer (score 0):

What did Jesus mean in John 1:47 regarding Nathanael: “an Israelite indeed”?
John 1:47:

> "Jesus saw Nathanael coming to Him, and said of him, 'Behold, an
> Israelite indeed, in whom there is no deceit!'” (emphasis added).

Jesus’ words to Nathanael indicated that he was an Israelite not merely by birth but by manifesting the same kind of faith and adherence to God’s will that his forefather Jacob did. Jesus’ words (which may reflect Ps 32:2) also indicate that there was nothing hypocritical or devious about Nathanael.

Psalm 32:2 NET

> 2 How blessed is the one  whose wrongdoing the Lord does not punish,in
> whose spirit there is no deceit.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with those who say the reference is a play off the fact that Jacob was famous for being a man of guile.

However let me add an idea that has not be mentioned yet. It's possible that Jesus was referring to Nathanael's brutal honesty when he responded: "can anything good come out of Nazareth." In other words, Jesus sensed in Nathanael a person who would speak his mind directly without caring much for polite social conventions. This characteristic is born out by the fact that Nathanael immediately changed his attitude and declared unambiguously: "“Rabbi, you are the Son of God; you are the King of Israel.”

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this reference yet so I'll post it here. This phrase "in whom is no deceit" is echoing a passage from Psalm 32:

‭‭Psalms‬ ‭32:1‭-‬2‬

> <sup>**1**</sup> Blessed is the one whose transgressions are forgiven, whose sins are covered. <sup>**2**</sup> Blessed is the one whose sin the Lord does not count against them and in whose spirit is no deceit.

In this psalm, David's focus is on confession. The practice of openly and honestly pouring out your heart to God: the good, bad, and ugly. A few verses later, David recounts how eager and willing God had been to pardon his sin, the moment it was confessed. Showing that God values total honesty and integrity, even when it's painful.

I don't know Nathaniel but I can say this: it is very tough to have a spirit with "no deceit." You can't make any excuses for your sins. There's no "burying it" and walking away. As a person of integrity, you can't help but know your own sinfulness.

So this quote was a genuine sign of God's love and approval of Nathaniel. Jesus used these words specifically to call his mind to Psalm 32. Because Nathaniel had shared in David's total honesty with God, God had also given him a share in the same grace and forgiveness He had shown to David.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: @agarza I will, was there any problem with this one?